# How to calculate Steady state nuclear magnetization in NMR

Tags: nuclear-magnetic-resonance

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_equations

In the Bloch Equations M0 is supposed to represent the steady nuclear magnetization. What determines this M0 value and how do you calculate it? Is it just the magnetic susceptibility constant times the applied static field?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don’t calculate $M_0$, typically it is measured. It is the magnetization that’s you measure in a proton density weighted image.

If you really wanted to calculate it you would need to know the total proton density in the material and the temperature. From that you can calculate the number of excess spins in the fully relaxed state, and then multiply by the magnetic moment for a single spin.